# shopify-api-node returns status 401 unauthorized for private app

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, shopify, shopify-app

I am attempting to make a NodeJS application utilizing this npm package called [shopify-node-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node)

Please note, this is a **private** app which was generated in the Shopify Partners account. I've passed the `shopName`, `apiKey` and `password` as instructed by the documentation.

```
    const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

    const shopify = new Shopify({
      shopName: 'your-shop-name',
      apiKey: 'your-api-key',
      password: 'your-app-password'
    });
```

However, when attempting to perform something as straightforward as this **GET**:

```
    shopify.product.get()
    .then(products =>  res.send(products))
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
```

I receive:

```
    {
        "name": "HTTPError",
        "hostname": "your-shop-name",
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/admin/products.json",
        "protocol": "https:",
        "statusCode": 401,
        "statusMessage": "Unauthorized",
        "headers": {...}
    }
```

To all the Shopify App/JavaScript specialists, please advise on what I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day my mistake here was an incorrect use of the API call from using these bindings.

Instead of:

```
 shopify.product.get()
.then(products =>  res.send(products))
.catch(err => res.send(err));
```

I should have been using this:

```
shopify.product.list()
.then(products =>  res.send(products))
.catch(err => res.send(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the API key to ensure you have given it the scope needed to access products. Failure to ask for read/write scope on products would be a good clue as to 401. That or you are not passing the api key and password as per what is presented to you in the shop.

Comment: "scope needed to access products" - is this a setting inside of the Shopify Partners account or a method inside of the Shopify-api-node module?

Comment: You set scope when you exchange oAuth tokens or when you click the drop-downs in the peivate App setup screen giving you the API keys in the shop itself.

Comment: I checked the store's Shopify Admin account and the app permissions are: Read products, variants, and collections. I also checked the Shopify Partner's account as well to verify the API key and API secret key of the private app are 1:1 w/ my code. Still no luck. I believe this is moreso of a learning curve issue I have with how to properly use these bindings from the Shopify-api-node library: https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node

Comment: The fact you get a response of 401 tells you that your API credentials are not being used properly then. Go through the docs on how to make calls to Shopify, and you'll be sailing smooth in no time. It is pretty simple and the same as the 10 million other API services out there.